# How to correctly set an array of fetched objects to a state in react and render the data in a FlatList

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-native, object, fetch-api

I can't seem to find a way to correctly type my Interfaces and Array of Objects to use in a FlatList.

I am using ReactNative with Typescript.

The json file I fetched was from the NewsAPI which provides JSON data like this.

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 10,
    -"articles": [
        -{
            -"source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "somename"
        },
        "author": "someauthor",
        "title": "sometitle",
        "description": "somedesc",
        "url": "someurl",
        "urlToImage": "someimage",
        "publishedAt": "somedate",
     },
    +{ … },
    ]
}
```

My current attempt looks like this but I can't wrap my head around the right method to use the keys for the renderItems and the keyExtractor of the FlatList.

```
interface IState {
news: {
    [key: string]: IArticles
},
loading: boolean
}

interface IArticles { //Since I don't actually want all the values of the object I left some out
    title: string,
    url: string,
    urlToImage: string
}

export default class NewsField extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
}

state: IState = {
    news: [],
    loading: true
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchNews(); //This is where I set the state and fetch the data
}

render() {
    return (
         <View>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.news}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.containerList}>
                            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                        </View>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={({ item, index }) => item.title.toString();}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: You haven't described what the problem is. Is there an error? Does anything render? Can you share the output with us?

Comment: Btwm, it looks like the shape of the JSON coming from that api is `articles: IArticles[]`, which means your `news` should probably be `news: IArticles[]`